# Python - Updating Json values dynamically by keymap

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to update json dynamically by set of "rule" keymap.

basically it's working for different fields but not for this specific case,
the sequence_handler function - get as the required sequence by name
and increment the global variable .

This updating the json as expected:

```py
CUSTOMER_NO = 1000
SUBSCRIBER_NO = 9000

def sequence_hanlder(sequence_name):
    globals()[sequence_name] += 1  
    return globals()[sequence_name]

my_json = { "subscriber_no": "val1", "customer_no": "val2"}

key_map = {"subscriber_no": sequence_hanlder("SUBSCRIBER_NO"),
 "customer_no": sequence_hanlder("CUSTOMER_NO")
 }
#this works
my_json['subscriber_no'] = sequence_hanlde("SUBSCRIBER_NO")
```

I'd like to key the update values by

```
 key_map(<filed_name>)())
```

but it leads to error:

```
my_json['subscriber_no'] = key_map['subscriber_no']()

...
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want. You seem to want a dictionary that returns an incrementing value each time you access a key?

Comment: Iain Shelvington ,  exactly, i want to be able to assign the specific field in the json the functionality describe in the keymap , I wonder how the sequence_hanlder function should be written to avoid that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says true, `sequence_hanlder("SUBSCRIBER_NO")` indeed is `int`. When you Look at examples (`A -> B` indicates a function that takes type A as input an returns B)

```
def f(s: str) -> int:
    return int(s) # its function str -> int
```

If you write `x = f("1")` then of course `x` has type **int**. When you create a dict, python evaluates values instantly and only once, so `{"key": f("1")}` becomes `{"key": 1}`. To make it work your `f` needs to return a function:

```
def f(s: str) -> typing.Callable[..., int]:
    return lambda: int(s) # that function returns function!
```

(If you are not familiar with lambda abstraction, you can find [many tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20lambda) about them).

The easies way is to use partial and a helper function:

```
from functools import partial

def helper(sequence_name):
    return partial(sequence_hanlder, sequence_name)

key_map = {
    "subscriber_no": helper("SUBSCRIBER_NO"),
    "customer_no": helper("CUSTOMER_NO"),
}
```

Our `helper` returns proper function so can be used in dict values

```
my_json['subscriber_no'] = key_map['subscriber_no']()
```

If you want to play a bit, you could write your own dict with lazy values evaluation (so while accessing key, not while creating  dictionary), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669367/setup-dictionary-lazily) you can find more information.

Comment: Thanks kosciej16 , this actually works but i'd like to understand better why it's happening and how i should write the sequence_hanlder function to avoid using the partial function

Comment: @AviC Updated, let me know if I should precise something more

Comment: So @AviC did it work for you?